# Are null characters in java.io.File valid for exists check?

Tags: java, file-io, operating-system

When a null is encountered in a filename in `java.io.File`, that character and all characters after it are ignored, resulting in some strange behavior in `File.exists()`.

Is this behavior some aspect of `java.io.File.exists()` that I've missed?

Example:

```
package os;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileNullCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File tmp = new File("a.txt");
        try
        {
            tmp.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        String a = "a.txt";
        System.out.printf("a.txt exists: %b (len=%d)%n",new File(a).exists(),a.length());
        
        String anull = new String(new byte[] { 'a', '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00 });
        System.out.printf("a.txt (null) exists: %b (len=%d)%n",new File(anull).exists(),anull.length());

        String anullx = new String(new byte[] { 'a', '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00, 'x' });
        System.out.printf("a.txt (nullx) exists: %b (len=%d)%n",new File(anullx).exists(),anullx.length());
    }
}
```

The results of running this.

```
a.txt exists: true (len=5)
a.txt (null) exists: true (len=6)
a.txt (nullx) exists: true (len=7)
```

The Linux system has the following JVM.

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

The behavior seems to be C-like and the string used to validate the file on the filesystem is truncated at the null.

But I would expect the behavior at Java to return false for `File.exists()` on these invalid filenames.

**Update: Sep 19, 2013**

Java 1.7.0 update 40 has fixed this as part of bug
[JDK-8014846 : File and other classes in java.io do not handle embedded nulls properly](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8014846)

Comment: That's an interesting interaction with the native API. Does it at least work consistently? I.e. does opening the files with the wrong names work as well?

Comment: Yes, you can even open read/write the file using the invalid file names.

Comment: I'd call this an implementation artifact, possibly a bug. Definitely not something that I'd depend on. In fact, U+0000 is about the only character that I'd never allow in a file name (even if the underlying OS would allow it, which I doubt many do).

Comment: Which characters/bytes are allowed depends on the OS and the file system used.  Unix allows more characters than Windows does.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I wouldn't allow the file seperator in a file name. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: yes, but the file separator varies ;-) What I'm trying to say was "I'd add the nul character (or U+0000 in Unicode) to the set of restricted characters, even if the OS didn't."

Comment: On RHEL 5.3 it appears you can have a `\u0000` provided it is not the first character in which case you get "No such file or directory"

Comment: The Javadocs for `String(byte[])` states: "The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified".  Just as an FYI

Comment: @BrianRoach changing to String(byte[], "UTF-8") doesn't change the behavior reported.  Thanks, I needed to force the charset anyway in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On RHEL it appears that the nul byte terminates the file name (as you might expect in C)

```
System.out.println("a exists " + new File("a").exists());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("a\u0000aa"));
fos.close();
System.out.println("a exists " + new File("a").exists());
```

prints

```
a exists false
a exists true
```

I suspect Java should prevent you from attempting to use a file name with a nul byte.

Answer (score 1):

If using JDK 1.7+ the java.nio.files.Paths.get(URI) can be used to test for Nul (it seems)

A modification to the original tests produces a useful Exception

```
package os;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileNullCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File tmp = new File("a.txt");
        try
        {
            tmp.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String a = "a.txt";
        testExists("a.txt", a);

        String anull = new String(new byte[] { 'a', '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00 }, "UTF-8");
        testExists("a.txt (null)", anull);

        String anullx = new String(new byte[] { 'a', '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00, 'x' }, "UTF-8");
        testExists("a.txt (nullx)", anullx);
    }

    private static void testExists(String label, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        System.out.printf("%s exists: %b%n", label, file.exists());
        System.out.printf("  filename.length = %d%n", filename.length());
        Path path = Paths.get(file.toURI());
        boolean symlink = Files.isSymbolicLink(path);
        System.out.printf("  nio issymlink = %b%n",symlink);
    }
}
```

Results in the output

```
a.txt exists: true
  filename.length = 5
  nio issymlink = false
a.txt (null) exists: true
  filename.length = 6
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Nul character not allowed: /home/joakim/code/Stackoverflow/a.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkNotNul(UnixPath.java:93)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2069)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixUriUtils.fromUri(UnixUriUtils.java:61)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getPath(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:97)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
    at os.FileNullCheck.testExists(FileNullCheck.java:39)
    at os.FileNullCheck.main(FileNullCheck.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is my 3rd attempt. I checked your code under Windows (Win 7, JDK 7 64 bit). It causes the same result:

```
a.txt exists: true (len=5)
a.txt (null) exists: true (len=6)
a.txt (nullx) exists: true (len=7)
```

In java sources we can see, that it uses `native` implementation of `getBooleanAttributes(File f)` method. It means that JVM interacts with **c/c++** libraries of JVM. In that case all strings with `0x00` symbol in it will be interpreted in libraries like strings only before `0x00` ('\0') symbol.

How this assumption could be checked? I have conducted a simple experiment. If my assumption about cutting this strings inside OS libraries is correct, then this code:

```
    String anull = new String(new byte[] { 'a',0x00 , '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00 });
    System.out.printf("a.txt (null) exists: %b (len=%d)%n",new File(anull).exists(),anull.length());
```

will return `false`. And yes, it is so:

```
a.txt (null) exists: false (len=7)
```

**UPD:**

This:

```
String anull = new String(new byte[] { 'a',0x00 , '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00 });
new File(anull).createNewFile();
```

will create a file named just `a` without any extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is determined by underlying OS and file system only. When you create `File` with a name that contains zeros, this filename is not changed during construction of `File`:

```
String anull = new String(new byte[] {'a', 0x00, '.', 't', 'x', 't', 0x00});
System.out.println(anull);
System.out.println(new File(anull).getPath());
```

The output is identical and contains zeros.

When `File` works with files it uses a file system (e.g. `java.io.FileSystem`), which implementation depends on OS and JDK (it's internal class). In Windows JDK almost all functions are native, so in this case this behavior is determined by underlying OS (or JDK dlls).